# How do I rebuild the JAR file for my Discord bot?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've had someone create a Discord bot for me. I need to change some grammar from it so I grabbed the source code from him and changed the title lines to what I need changed.

Example:

```
.setTitle("Tier information here")
```

Fixed:

```
.setTitle("Tier information:")
```

When I try and create the JAR file and upload it onto my host, it gives an error.

Am I supposed to do something else after I change the titles? Or am I just messing up on the JAR creation part?

My pom.xml contains:

```
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.4</version>
```

maven-shade-plugin and 3.2.4 is red. Does that have anything to do with it?

I updated maven-shade-plugin and refreshed and recreated the JAR and it's still not working.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please [edit] your question and include the full error message.

Comment: How are you creating the JAR? What commands are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You have a pom.xml in the sources. That strongly indicates you should be running a maven build. In case you never heard of Maven, check http://maven.apache.org/

So what you need to do:

- ensure you have a recent version of Java installed
- ensure you have a recent version of Maven installed
- ensure you can run `mvn` from the command line

Then on the command line cd into your project directory. Run `mvn package`. Maven should startup, download all further dependencies and run until your jar file exists.